# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Screen freezes after login when waking laptop up from suspend

Tags: login, suspend, 20.04

I have got a new Entroware Apollo with Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed. I have had an occasional but not infrequent issue of my computer screen freezing after login when it is woken up but have no issues at boot. Once I type my password in, it freezes and despite waiting for a long time it doesn't unfreeze.

Is anybody familiar with a method of fixing this or know whether this is a bug?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this very frustrating bug. The workaround that I use is to enter a terminal using `ctrl+alt+f2` (you may also have to hit the `fn` key if you have one) then kill the display manager. On my distro (Ubuntu Studio with XFCE), the default display manager is lightdm. You can find yours by running `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` in a terminal. Whatever that says, to kill it from the terminal, just run `sudo killall $DM`, where `$DM` is the display manager you see.

Comment: Thanks, I may try this in future, I haven’t had the problem for a couple of weeks because I just stopped my laptop from locking so the problem does happen. This will at least allow me to lock my laptop without fear of it crashing.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Xubuntu 20.04 - gui just freezes after login after laptop wake from suspension. Any ideas how this issue can be debuged and solved without restarting lightdm or gdm from the terminal?

Comment: Killing DM (in my case ```lightdm```) kills the session which the laptop tries to wake up into. Is this a ```lightdm``` issue? or any DM malfunctions the same way?

Comment: I'm having the same issue in standard Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome/gdm3.  Killing gdm3 also works for me.

Comment: I am also having a similar problem on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS - doesn't wake up properly after suspend and the mouse menu and window buttons don't work. It worked fine until a couple of weeks ago so something must have gone wrong in the updates somewhere. Repeating Alt-F4 to get to the login screen and then logging back in again fixes it, for some unknown reason. Major bug which needs to be fixed by someone pronto.

Comment: I recently ran into this on a Thinkpad. There was a setting in the BIOS that seems to have resolved the issue. I'm not familiar with Entroware, but since they're shipping machines with Ubuntu preinstalled, things should presumably work out of the box. I would contact Entroware directly about the issue to get it resolved.

Comment: You can upgrade to 21.10, ubuntu 20.04 is not recommended by me. Very buggy version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same problem with fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.10.

After some research, i found that the `/etc/securetty` file didn't exist and `gdm3` systemd service reported this:

[image: Error message]

In text form:

```
pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

I created this file and now suspend is working correctly

Guide: [Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, /etc/securetty: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239503/ubuntu-20-04-and-20-10-etc-securetty-no-such-file-or-directory/1239563#1239563)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the TPM module in BIOS system worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ubuntu for the last 2 years. I faced the issue of the freezing screen after unlocking the laptop. I tried various steps but nothing works for very long. 
Upgrading to SSD (solid-state drive) from a normal mechanical hard drive (HDD) has solved this problem for me. It has been 8 months, I didn't face any problems so far.

Comment: Did you install a fresh installation of Ubuntu on the SSD? If so, then it could just be the a fresh install fixed the issue, rather than the SSD.

Comment: Yes, it's a fresh installation on SSD but It has been 8 months and I have not faced that issue. Earlier even after reinstallation, the issue use to appear in the 3rd or 4th week.

Comment: I had an SSD in place for the install. Initially had the default DM but later switched to Xfce. That was all working fine for a few weeks, and then it recently started having this problem for no apparent reason. So at least in my case, having an SSD made no difference.

Comment: At least in my case, this seems to have something to do with Xfce. Switched back to Gnome and even installed MATE to compare, and neither is having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue for quite some years as well. It is not nvidia related (as some people state) as I use Intel builtin graphics. I've already had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04. Usually my notebook is docked via USB-C to an external monitor and Ethernet-NIC, wifi stays on. My gdm3 login screen locks now and then when I undock my notebook and close the lid (or other way round). After opening the lid I neither can type in a password nor does fingerprint unlocking work.

I suspect network share automounter. Prior 20.04 I used autofs and these freezes happend very often. I changed the automount-scripts to detect my file server and things got better. With 20.04 I am using systemd to automount and things got even better. But still from time to time the login window just freezes. When I am still at home connected to my home wifi sometimes the login screen unfreezes after a couple of minutes - it looks like it needs some time for a timeout to hit.

If the freeze doesn't go away I switch to a terminal console and issue

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

But very often that doesn't help anymore so I need to power down the notebook.

I've filed bug reports some years ago without any progress.
[Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/1874835)
[Gnome upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/618)