# Application randomly crashing

Tags: crash

This is my PC at work. It is Dell Precision 3630 Tower Workstation. When we purchased it, it initially came with one 256 gb ssd + 1 tb hd. I had Kubuntu 18.04 installed on it with root on the ssd and /home on the HD.

The issue I am having is basically any application I have open, there is like 20% chance for it to crash every 20 min. I use mostly Visual Studio Code (VS code) on it and literally every 20-40 min, the editor stops responding and I have to wait until it says to reopen or exit (I don't lose any files/unsaved data in this program). I believe VS code spawns multiple processes and only one process crashes since I can still click on the menubar. Also, different windows don't crash. It is just anything inside the crashed window is not responding.

This issue is not exclusive to VS code, Google Chrome and other work applications crash and disappear completely. In addition, a notification shows up every once in a while saying Ethernet connection disconnected then reconnected 1 sec after. No internet is lost.

I thought the issue might be with KDE plasma 5 (since this was the first time I use it), so I installed Gnome and the issue was the same. Also note that I have 32GB RAM on this PC (with 4GB swap) so running out of memory is never an issue.

I did the following and all of them failed (mostly hardware):

- I installed a newer kernel (5.7) and still same issue.
- I removed the ssd and hd and installed a new 1tb ssd and installed Kubuntu 20.04 from scratch on it (root and /home in same partition). Same issue.
- I did a memory test using memtest86 (https://www.memtest86.com/). No issues in 2 hour run (Also tested again in diagnostic tools)
- There is a Built-in self test (BIST) with the PSU. I tested it. No issues.
- I ran the diagnostic tools that comes in the BIOS. It tests CPU/GPU/memory/network card/HD/PCIe bus/cables/fans with different stress tests. No issues.

The PC is reported to support Linux (We bought it with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled). I also have latest BIOS firmware for this PC (reset it too) and latest firmware for the new SSD (1TB Samsung 860 EVO).

I am not sure what is causing this issue and I tried almost everything with no hint on the cause. Any suggestion on how to fix this issue. Below is link to logs from /var/log/syslog for 1 hour where VS code crashed once and the LAN connection restarted twice (changed name/ip for privacy reason)

[logs](https://pastebin.com/cUz5C6js)

Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-8700 @ 3.20GHz, 6 Cores, 12 Logical
- RAM: 2x16 GB (2666MHz)
- GPU: AMD Radeon Pro WX 2100

Edit: VS Code crashed 5 minutes ago. Here is the output of journalctl in the past 5 min.

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-07-17 20:41:33 EDT, end at Sun 2020-07-26 17:23:31 EDT. --
Jul 26 17:18:55 PC1-Linux1 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Jul 26 17:18:55 PC1-Linux1 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Jul 26 17:18:55 PC1-Linux1 systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Jul 26 17:22:38 PC1-Linux1 kernel: traps: code[1671] general protection fault ip:55dacd92bda9 sp:7ffdef785fe0 error:0 in code[55dacc0bb000+51c7000]
Jul 26 17:23:28 PC1-Linux1 sudo[3151]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 26 17:23:31 PC1-Linux1 sudo[3151]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 26 17:23:31 PC1-Linux1 sudo[3151]: user1 : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user1 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-5 minutes
Jul 26 17:23:31 PC1-Linux1 sudo[3151]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Edit2: LAN connection crashed too. Adding output of journalctl in the past 5 min

```
Jul 26 17:36:49 PC1-Linux1 sudo[3469]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 26 17:40:12 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <error> [1595799612.7782] dhcp4 (eno1): error -113 dispatching events
Jul 26 17:40:12 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799612.7782] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> fail
Jul 26 17:40:12 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799612.7783] device (eno1): DHCPv4: trying to acquire a new lease within 90 seconds
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6503] device (eno1): DHCPv4: grace period expired
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6504] device (eno1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <warn>  [1595799702.6548] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6559] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6562] device (eno1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Withdrawing address record for MAC_REMOVED on eno1.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address MAC_REMOVED.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6568] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Interface eno1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6568] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed fail -> done
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Withdrawing address record for REMOVED_IP51 on eno1.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address REMOVED_IP51.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Interface eno1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 dbus-daemon[702]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=704 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unc>
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6629] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (80d4d697-a540-3f51-9017-549c2ae2ce5b)
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6639] device (eno1): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (80d4d697-a540-3f51-9017-549c2ae2ce5b)
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address MAC_REMOVED.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] offline
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6640] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6642] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Registering new address record for MAC_REMOVED on eno1.*.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6644] device (eno1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 dbus-daemon[702]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6649] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6651] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 nm-dispatcher[3535]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '3600'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name          => 'REMOVED_DOMAIN'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name_servers  => 'REMOVED_IP2 REMOVED_IP1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option expiry               => '1595803302'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option host_name            => 'user1_e4b97af22165'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option ip_address           => 'REMOVED_IP51'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address REMOVED_IP51.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_routers    => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 avahi-daemon[698]: Registering new address record for REMOVED_IP51 on eno1.IPv4.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6713] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6714] dhcp4 (eno1): option routers              => 'REMOVED_IP'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6714] dhcp4 (eno1): option subnet_mask          => 'REMOVED_IP'
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6714] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6723] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6736] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6738] device (eno1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6740] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6746] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6746] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6750] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1595799702.6752] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 whoopsie[1011]: [17:41:42] online
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:42 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:43 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:44 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jul 26 17:41:45 PC1-Linux1 systemd-resolved[656]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Output of `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       1.3Gi        28Gi        52Mi       1.5Gi        29Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C memory`

```
 *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2.5.0
       date: 02/05/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 9
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA82GU6JJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 0
          serial: 72DB71AA
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA82GU6JJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 1
          serial: 72DB71A7
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: DIMM3
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: DIMM4
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 14
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 15
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 16
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:4000114000-4000115fff memory:4000119000-4000119fff
```

No errors in memtest. Screenshots:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXofr.jpg)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTcUP.jpg)
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rioJ.jpg)

Comment: Does this happen immediately after booting? And does it depend on how many programs you have open?

Comment: @guttermonk Yes, it can start happening immediately after booting. It doesn't seem to depend on number of programs open as the LAN connection crashes with no application open and VS Code crashes with only one window open. However, frequency of programs crashing increases with more programs open. It's like each program has a chance to crash independently of what is open.

Comment: Also, I have to mention that Kate/Konsole(terminal) can crash.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show the last 5 minutes of system logs.

Comment: @waltinator I included the output in the post. VS Code crashed during that time. 4th line seems related to the issue but couldn't find anything about it online.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't run memtest long enough to get 4/4 passes on your 32G. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. What processor are you running? Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema You are right. I didn't run until 4/4 passes. I ran it for 2 hours and IIRC it did 1 pass. I read somewhere that 99% of the issues are caught in the first 10 min of memtest. I can try running it overnight. Do you think I should? Another option I have is I can grab a RAM chip from another PC that is working and see if that fixes the issue. I don't overclock anything on this PC. The things you requested are now included in the post.

Comment: @Topa I've run memtest only to have it fail on the 3/4th test. So yes, please do run it overnight. DON'T start swapping RAM from another PC. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema No errors in memtest. 4/4 passes. I included a screenshot.

Comment: Good news. Two suggestions. 1) try Ubuntu 20.04 and see if the problem is gone, 2) you're getting an error "pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory", which can be solved... look at the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239503/20-04-etc-securetty-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @heynnema I am already on Ubuntu 20.04 (actually Kubunutu 20.04) but I had the same issue in both display managers when I was on 18.04. I doubt that the issue is with /etc/securetty. I don't think I had that issue on 18.04. I'll try the fix.
I personally think the issue is with PSU or motherboard even though neither are showing any issues with their respective tests.

Comment: /etc/securetty is not the problem, it's just something that needs fixing. I agree, I think it's coming down to PSU.

Comment: @heynnema The /etc/securetty error doesn't show up anymore after applying the fix. I asked a coworker who has the exact same PC and they don't have any crashing in their PC (Ubuntu 18.04). I am thinking it is definitely PSU or motherboard. I'll try swapping PSU with another PC. Thanks for helping me diagnose this whole issue and the quick responses.

Comment: Please keep me posted, ok?

Comment: @heynnema I finally got the chance to swap the PSU and that sadly didn't fix the issue :( I guess it is the motherboard that is defective. However, before doing that, is it possible that the RAM chip has an issue but memtest can't detect it. I probably should test swapping the RAM chips and using different slots in the motherboard.

Comment: @Topa Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? What are the CPU temps running at?

Comment: @heynnema They are not overclocked and temperature for CPU is 33-35C and for GPU is 44C.

Comment: @Topa Although I don't think it's a RAM problem, you could pull out ONE RAM DIMM at a time, and run that way for a while and see if you have problems. Make sure to return the DIMMs to their original slots during/after troubleshooting. Let me post an answer about increasing your swap, and we can try that too.

Comment: @Topa Do the /swapfile first.

Comment: @heynnema I am not sure why your answer disappeared. Anyway I tried pulling out one RAM DIMM at a time and testing it. I also tried different slots. None of them solved the issue. It seems the motherboard is defective. I'll see how we can get a replacement from Dell or send it for repair under warranty (but I highly doubt Dell will be convinced that it is defective).

Comment: @Topa i pulled my answer because it only dealt with a larger /swapfile, and you indicated *"I don't think this will fix the issue"*. I can put it back, if you like. I didn't think RAM was the issue, as `memtest` had passed. I'm not sure what's wrong with your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Dell and they sent me a replacement motherboard with cpu. I thought they will take ages to send me what I need but they were very fast (aka next day they shipped them). I guess if you buy from the business division, you get better service.

I installed the replacements and the issue has be fixed. I guess the motherboard or the cpu have to be the issues. I am still having the other issues with the network card restarting but I believe this issue is unrelated and has to do with our corporate network.

Also, special thanks to @heynnema for helping me go through the debugging steps. It helped me narrow down the issue.