# Desktop Environment Initialization Delay in 20.04 (PLEASE HELP!)

Tags: 20.04, login, xorg, lightdm, desktop-environments

## Specs

Display Manager: `lightdm 1.30.0`

Desktop Environment: `gnome 3.36.3` (though I also tried xfce)

## Problem/Background

Once I login, all I can see (for at least a minute) is the wallpaper and mouse. Eventually the rest of the desktop environment is loaded and everything is good to go. If I log out and back in, I don't have the same issue I do at startup. **Additionally, I can't use a tty to find out what is going on because login to the tty takes forever - perhaps a related problem (authentication)?**

Originally I thought the problem was `lightdm` but it turns out if I switch to `gdm3` I have the same problem except instead of seeing the walpaper and mouse I just have a black screen. I am now convinced the problem lies in the GNOME DE.

## Attempts

- Installation of `haveged`
- Disabling of the `lightdm.service` and `startx`ing
- Disabling/removal of gnome extensions
- Installation/use of `gdm3`
- Installation/use of `xubuntu-desktop`
- Use of both NVIDIA proprietary and nouveau video drivers
- Upgrading to 20.10 Groovy Gorilla (trying this currently - will update if works/doesn't)

## Logs [EDITED]

I took a more targeted approach and as soon as I entered my login credentials around 15:06:20, I timed the duration to DE initialization (~58s). All logs below are taken from `journalctl` in that timeframe and the first three are tailored to a specific category.

#### `lightdm`

```
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user lightdm.
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user sterlingbutters by (uid=0)
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user lightdm.
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user lightdm.
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user sterlingbutters by (uid=0)
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu lightdm[2785]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Aug 25 15:06:23 butters-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user lightdm.
```

#### `systemd`

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bHsPmY7DH9/

#### `gnome-shell`

```
Aug 25 15:06:49 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3336]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Aug 25 15:06:52 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:52 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5' unit='evolution-source-registry.service' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=3343 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server ">
Aug 25 15:06:53 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=3343 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server>
Aug 25 15:06:54 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1464]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu polkitd(authority=local)[1866]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.78 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1464]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:49 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3336]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Aug 25 15:06:52 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:52 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5' unit='evolution-source-registry.service' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=3343 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server ">
Aug 25 15:06:53 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar8' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.52' (uid=1000 pid=3343 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server>
Aug 25 15:06:54 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1464]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu polkitd(authority=local)[1866]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.78 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 25 15:06:55 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1464]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:56 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3438]: Supported
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code accessed the property 'ScreencastIface' on the module 'screencast'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbol>
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for EasyScreenCast.indicator
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:81:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026:21
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for EasyScreenCast.indicator
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:84:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026:21
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for EasyScreenCast.indicator
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:87:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026:21
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Slider
                                                  _createMIInfoDelayRec@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:606:9
                                                  _add_recording_delay_sub_menu@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:347:26
                                                  _init_main_menu@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:141:14
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:119:14
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026:21
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Slider
                                                  _createMIInfoDelayRec@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:610:9
                                                  _add_recording_delay_sub_menu@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:347:26
                                                  _init_main_menu@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:141:14
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:119:14
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026:21
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code tried to set a deprecated GObject property.
                                                  2 _createMIInfoDelayRec() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":610:33]
                                                  4 _add_recording_delay_sub_menu() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":347:25]
                                                  6 _init_main_menu() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":141:13]
                                                  8 _init() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":119:13]
                                                  10 enable() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":1026:20]
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code tried to set a deprecated GObject property.
                                                  2 _createMIInfoDelayRec() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":610:33]
                                                  4 _add_recording_delay_sub_menu() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":347:25]
                                                  6 _init_main_menu() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":141:13]
                                                  8 _init() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":119:13]
                                                  10 enable() ["/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js":1026:20]
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for EasyScreenCast.indicator
                                                  _enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:627:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js:1030:15
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ClipboardIndicator
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/extension.js:88:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com/extension.js:860:26
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Initializing Handy Scripts 2 version 3
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Enabling Handy Scripts 2 version 3
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Menu.Menu
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:49:7
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:244:9
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Menu.Menu
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:50:7
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:244:9
Aug 25 15:06:57 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Menu.Menu
                                                  _renderMenu@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:228:7
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:52:12
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/handyscripts2@lucaskenda.com.ar/extension.js:244:9
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code accessed the property 'GSETTINGS_HIDDEN' on the module '_config'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols >
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code accessed the property 'GSETTINGS_KNOWN' on the module '_config'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols t>
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code accessed the property 'EXTENSION_NAME' on the module '_config'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to>
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ActivitiesButton
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for AppMenuButton
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for DateMenuButton
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for DwellClickIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:231:32
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for DwellClickIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:239:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ATIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:231:32
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ATIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:239:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for InputSourceIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:231:32
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for InputSourceIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:239:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for AggregateMenu
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for EasyScreenCast.indicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for ClipboardIndicator
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Menu.Menu
                                                  _refreshIndicators@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:241:17
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:151:14
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Indicator
                                                  _init@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:54:9
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:155:31
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Some code accessed the property 'GSETTINGS_ISINDICATORSHOWN' on the module '_config'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. An>
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for Indicator
                                                  enable@/home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/icon-hider@kalnitsky.org/extension.js:170:1
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Found user extension desktop-icons@csoriano, but not loading from /home/sterlingbutters/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano directory as part of session mode.
Aug 25 15:06:58 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: JS ERROR: Could not load extension apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com: Error: Missing metadata.json
Aug 25 15:06:59 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:59 butters-ubuntu dbus-daemon[2940]: [session uid=1000 pid=2940] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.Notifications' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=3284 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 25 15:06:59 butters-ubuntu gnome-shell[3284]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
```

#### Untailored Log

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9C9CSr5v5F/

EDIT: `systemd` analysis:

[Plot](https://ibb.co/wskTyZR)

```
~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 16.585s (firmware) + 7.742s (loader) + 24.702s (kernel) + 33.323s (userspace) = 1min 22.355s 
graphical.target reached after 32.496s in userspace

~$ systemd-analyze blame
18.280s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
17.725s udisks2.service                                      
 9.125s tor@default.service                                  
 8.747s avahi-daemon.service                                 
 8.746s bluetooth.service                                    
 8.742s NetworkManager.service                               
 8.499s switcheroo-control.service                           
 8.472s systemd-logind.service                               
 8.329s thermald.service                                     
 8.321s wpa_supplicant.service                               
 7.567s snapd.service                                        
 7.425s dev-sdb1.device                                      
 5.471s apt-daily.service                                    
 4.737s accounts-daemon.service                              
 3.332s lightdm.service                                      
 3.110s gpu-manager.service                                  
 3.107s networking.service                                   
 3.079s rsyslog.service                                      
 3.036s grub-common.service                                  
 2.992s stunnel4.service                                     
 2.931s dev-loop0.device                                     
 2.909s dev-loop2.device                                     
 2.882s systemd-resolved.service                             
 2.768s colord.service                                       
 2.729s dev-loop1.device                                     
 2.719s dev-loop4.device                                     
 2.704s dev-loop5.device                                     
 2.700s dev-loop6.device                                     
 2.694s dev-loop3.device                                     
 2.685s dev-loop7.device                                     
 2.587s virtualbox.service                                   
 2.512s polkit.service                                       
 2.317s ufw.service                                          
 2.301s ssh.service                                          
 2.218s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
 1.545s systemd-udevd.service                                
 1.396s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
 1.269s apparmor.service                                     
 1.168s hddtemp.service                                      
 1.130s kerneloops.service                                   
 1.122s rc-local.service                                     
 1.121s systemd-modules-load.service                         
 1.096s vboxweb.service                                      
 1.074s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
  947ms alsa-restore.service                                 
  873ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
  866ms lm-sensors.service                                   
  760ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
  724ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
  718ms logrotate.service                                    
  710ms upower.service                                       
  671ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
  621ms slim.service                                         
  588ms systemd-sysusers.service
~
~

~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @32.496s
└─multi-user.target @32.496s
  └─networkd-dispatcher.service @14.215s +18.280s
    └─basic.target @13.897s
      └─sockets.target @13.895s
        └─snapd.socket @13.887s +6ms
          └─sysinit.target @13.785s
            └─snapd.apparmor.service @13.113s +671ms
              └─apparmor.service @11.842s +1.269s
                └─local-fs.target @11.842s
                  └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @28.585s
                    └─run-snapd-ns.mount @24.141s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @5.411s
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @4.828s +579ms
                          └─systemd-sysusers.service @4.236s +588ms
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.087s +131ms
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @3.850s
                                └─-.mount @2.126s
                                  └─system.slice @2.126s
                                    └─-.slice @2.126s
```

Note my mileage varies with `critical-chain` i.e. sometimes these processes (the ones with `+<time>`) add up to less than a few seconds. That is, the `networkd-dispatcher` does not normally take that long to initialize.

Comment: Does this help https://askubuntu.com/q/1239503/816190?

Answer (score 1):

The PAM errors are indirectly coming from /etc/pam.d/lightdm:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
#session required        pam_loginuid.so
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

Have you tried looking at Settings Manager -> System (section) -> Session and Startup -> Advanced (tab) - I've got my "Launch KDE services at startup" disabled.

Also on the "Application Autostart" it might list kwallet or other KDE items. I have a minimalist selection of gnome/kde items - all gnome except "SSH Key Agent (GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent)" and "GNOME settings override migration" are not checked, and nothing KDE releated.

Comment: Looks like `Settings Manager` is the "Graphical Settings Manager for Xfce 4" - I am using GNOME and don't seem to have that option in my settings. However I don't see any non-GNOME entries in my startup applications

Comment: Ah - didn't realise you were using Gnome.

Could try creating a new user and see if that has the same issue. Or switch to xfce4 :-)

Comment: didn't have any better luck with xfce4 - so maybe not the Desktop environment after all... but it is 100% something between the DM and the DE

Answer (score 1):

### Disable `networkd-dispatcher`

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/clu0lj/short_guide_to_improve_slow_boot_on_ubuntu_1804/):

#### Disable networkd services:

If you are not a system admin you don't need this. Gui uses network-manger (and it has it's own dispatcher) anyway.

```
sudo apt-get remove networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd.service
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service
```

There are other boot speed tips but this appears most relevant to your case.

### Bug Report

There is a bug report on your issue:

- [pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/1860826)

It seems to have begun with **20.04** as **16.04** doesn't seem to have the problem:

```
$ ll /etc/securetty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4038 Mar 29  2016 /etc/securetty
```

You should subscribe to the bug report and follow progress.

Comment: I do get that error in `journalctl` but the bug doesn't say anything about a login delay - maybe I'll provide my experience there and hope it is related

Comment: @SterlingButters can you run `systemd-analyze blame` and include output in your question?

Comment: Happy to - please see EDIT. Sorry for late response

Comment: Per comment thread on that bug: 
>  Would this bug cause a gnome-session initialization delay? 
No, it would not. The sum totality of the impact of this bug is the extra
warning messages in the log files.

Comment: @SterlingButters Thanks for the systemd timings, I've updated answer with some tips.

Comment: @SterlingButters There are speed improvements for `udisks2` service here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239449